# How to add a input password type Field in magento 2 checkout page based on a condition?

Tags: magento2, checkout

[image: screenshot]

I'm seeking guidance on how to implement a custom field for a social security number in the checkout process, but only under specific conditions: the cart value must exceed $2500, and the website URL must be `baseurl/us/` (indicating the US store). Additionally, I need to ensure that the entered value is saved on the backend. Could you provide the necessary steps to achieve this?

Comment: Well you should add your field like any other permanent field, then you just have to play in js / knockout witht he cart amount to show or hide your field.

Comment: Hi @Sreyas let me know if you still need a detailed answer, I can provide. Thanks.